# How to convert this request to LINQ?

Tags: mysql, linq

- SELECT StepID, count(*) as nb FROM Question GROUP BY StepID ORDER by nb;*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably go through the basics of LINQ. Microsoft Docs has a whole section dedicated to LINQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

If you have your data in a List called as `questions` of type, `List<Question>` then you should be able to convert your Query like this:

```
var ret = from q in questions
          group q by q.StepId into grouped
          let count = grouped.Count()
          orderby count
          select new { StepId = grouped.Key, nb = count };
```

Comment: (1) groups is a `IGrouping<,>`, so get the key from its `.Key` property (2) groups identifies a single grouping, so don't use plural name for that. (3): don't Count() twice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Query comprehension syntax:

```
from q in questions
group q by q.StepId into g
select new { StepId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() } into stepCount
orderby stepCount.Count
select stepCount;
```

Exact same in method syntax (which I prefer, since it can all query syntax can plus more and also often is more compact):

```
questions
.GroupBy(q => q.StepId)
.Select(g => new { StepId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
.OrderBy(stepCount => stepCount.Count)
```

Variant using another `GroupBy` overload:

```
questions
.GroupBy(q => q.StepId, (key, values) => new { StepId = key, Count = values.Count() })
.OrderBy(stepCount => stepCount.Count);
```

Comment: Would be happy if you then upvoted the answer and possibly mark it as accepted (or the other answer, since it's about the same). Hunting reputation... :-)